# Is there a way to add a button to attach file to email?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, email-attachments, email

in my case, I have to add the email button on the file list but before it I must be signed first so that the file can be viewed, this email button when clicked the file will automatically be in the form of attachment when sending mail. In that cases is it possible without having to download the file first and then browse the file as attachment ?

Comment: Question not very clear

Comment: You want to add a mail-to button which attaches a file?

Comment: @AniMenon yes, the button is on every list files. For example there is a file with the name 'office.pdf' and the mail-to button on it, if I click it the file will be attached as attachement. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic version (using php):

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );
$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );
return $email->Send();
```

Reference : [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

Using laravel 5.0:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

Refer : [Laravel mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage)